# Calculate real-time transfer rate of MediaRecorder while streaming over a socket

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder

I am using MediaRecorder for capturing user's voice and streaming it in AMR-WB format over a Wi-Fi socket connection:

`mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(socket).getFileDescriptor());`

I want to display the transfer rate on screen and I looking for the best way to implement this.
I can think of two solutions myself:

- Create a LocalSocket-LocalServerSocket loop and transfer the data using buffers. This could add unnecessary delay and increase performance overhead.
- Calculate the transfer data based on the codec's characteristics. e.g., (size of each sample) * (samples per second). This solution does not work for networks with random delays or codecs with variable encoding rates.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe()` will create a pipe for you.

You can then write to the pipe and count the bytes you read from the other end before streaming them off into the aether...

Comment: I still need to buffer incoming data from one pipe and write it to the other one. Am I right?

Comment: Yeah, just like you were planning with a socket, but a bit less fuss.